# Junit : Cannot test header information in the response

Tags: java, junit, mockito, junit4, testcase

I am new to JUnit. I am trying to write a test case for java filter. Following is the filter code -

```
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException,
        IOException {
    response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    if (request.getHeader("Access-Control-Request-Method") != null && "OPTIONS".equals(request.getMethod())) {
        response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE");
        response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With,Origin,Content-Type, Accept, authSessionId");
    }
    filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
}
```

Following is the testcase that I have written -

```
   @Test
   public void testSomethingAboutDoFilter() throws ServletException, IOException {
    CorsFilter cf = new CorsFilter();
    HttpServletRequest req = mock(HttpServletRequest.class);
    HttpServletResponse rsp = mock(HttpServletResponse.class);
    FilterChain mockChain = mock(FilterChain.class);
    rsp.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE");
    when(req.getHeader("Access-Control-Request-Method")).thenReturn("abc");
    when(req.getMethod()).thenReturn("OPTIONS");
    cf.doFilterInternal(req, rsp, mockChain);
    String rspHeader = rsp.getHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods");
    System.out.println(rspHeader);
    }
```

The notion that I have in my mind is to check for what is added to the response and to match it to validate the test case. But for some reason I am getting null when I check -

```
   rsp.getHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods");
```

I tried finding out what could be the reason behind this and found that the header itself is not set. What should be the reason behind this and how can the test the code in that case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`rsp.addHeader` is also a mocked method and values you set there are not returned via `rsp.getHeader`. But you can verify if methods on your mock object are invoked using `verify` method. If you really want to have `addHeader` to work together with `getHeader`, you should consider using a spy object that is backed by a real object. I would `verify` that `addHeader` was called with right arguments using `verify(rsp).addHeader(...)`.

Comment: could you please give an example

Comment: Just try `verify(rsp).addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods")`. For more complex examples with matchers see http://site.mockito.org/mockito/docs/current/org/mockito/Mockito.html#3